# Spin Character like Sonic or Blanca (Root Pivot Around Spine)

Tags: transforms, rigify, pose-mode

I want to pivot root of armature around spine (multiple times) in pose mode as I animate fight scene. This is easy using transform slider in object mode but origin keeps changing. Below is the condensed version of what I tried:

1. constraints (pivot/transform/child) - works shortly before rig floats away...connected empty to spine and did same thing
2. change pivot to 3D cursor - works but slider only goes to 360
3. move root in edit mode - works until actually pose character then center off

Comment: On point 2.: slider might only go to 360, but you can usually enter higher values manually in many fields. I just don't know which slider you are referring to now.

Comment: Thank you I guess iPhone pics are too big to post but it’s a slider that appears on the left side of the viewport when you pivot around 3D cursor....I did try manual entry along the x axis but it still stops at 360 for some reason